# .NET Core 2.x HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-2.2

Google believes ssl is required at my site.  Most people bookmarked it with ssl.  I am switching host companies and ssl is not really needed.  With Core 2.2, how can I convert https requests to http?  Note, this is opposite to the existing Q and A.  I have tried removing the https enforcement in the startup class.  This isn't enough if they are coming in with https.

Comment: Maybe an explicit redirection to http instead of https? In case of having an outer nginx, it’s easy to implement, otherwise you should fire up a separate service, which handles https connections.

Comment: With a free cert using Lets Encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org) there really shouldn’t be a reason to go with http, regardless of what your site is doing. This would be the easiest solution IMO. Have you tried that route?

Comment: My undestanding is that I would also need to terminate my domain registration associated with my old host, and start a new one (in concert with the certificate).  Because it is not a new registration, the fees are extremely high.  Just to be sure, I will send your link to support desk and ask.

Comment: Unless you are running a business with special requirements on certificates (enhanced security and so on), the free certificates from Let's Encrypt are enough and widely supported. There is no such thing called "terminate my domain registration", as you can always transfer your registered domain to another domain management service. Domains and your hosting platforms are separate so that you can choose different providers and be flexible. Of course, that goes beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.